# Cannot install Shapely on Windows

Tags: python, pip

```
ERROR: Shapely-1.6.4.post2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I cannot install Shapely with:

```
pip install "C:/path.../Shapely-1.6.4.post2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
* pip install --upgrade pip
* Python version 3.6.4, Windows 64 bit
```

Should I be installing another version? cp36 and win_amd64 looks correct. Unless amd means the CPU? In that case I have Intel i5. I don't see that version so I don't think that's it...

Any other suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: Downloaded wheel from here: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely

Comment: Can you check that `where python` and `where pip` point to the same python installation? Also try `python -m pip install <your whl file>`. The file you have should be correct for your python version

Answer (score 0):

There's a helpful complete guide [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/install-shapely-on-windows-72b6581bb46c) to do so. Windows have many problems with python wheel files. If you want my advice, you better don't use Windows for python programming, Linux is perfect for such a thing. You can use Ubuntu which is great and stable.

If you really want to program python in Windows, I suggest you to install and use [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/). It's a great tool and helps you with installing python packages and programming in python.

**EDIT:** I tried the Anaconda way and it works fine. After installing [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) I opened `Anaconda Powershell Prompt` as admin (cause there was permission problem for me in installing Shapely!) and then ran the command `conda install shapely`. Once installation completed, I ran the command `jupyter notebook` and in jupyter I was able to use Shapely.

[image: shapely imported in jupyter]

I installed the Shapely in the base environment of conda which is not good. If you want use Anaconda, you better learn how to [manage environments in conda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html).

Comment: I have seen that guide. And I checked to make sure that I downloaded the correct versions before I posted so that's why I'm sure what is wrong. Never heard of why we should not use Windows. I'm new and learning just the basic necessities before I overload myself with too much information. Although, I'm starting a new job tomorrow and they're giving us Macs...

Comment: Good, MacOS is fine. But for Windows, try the anaconda way: first install anaconda, then open "anaconda terminal" and run the command `conda install shapely`.

Comment: @Julian there is absolutely nothing wrong with programming python on a windows machine.